# Issue in writing json to excel file in python

Tags: python, json, excel

I am trying to get json output of via one of API request , which i wanted then load that into excel file
The problem is the response i get from api, if i dump it to json.dumps() method, its becoming not parsable. But if i try to parse it as text, then tried to format it json formatter its parsing
Though i wrote code to write to csv below, but i wanted it to excel file..
Here is my sample `respone.text` variable in my actual code looks like:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "eventName": {
                "value": "EndRequest",
                "localizedValue": "EndRequest"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxx/extensions/enablevmaccess/events/xxxxxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxxxxx",
            "level": "Informational",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxx",
            "resourceProviderName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute"
            },
            "operationName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write"
            },
            "status": {
                "value": "Succeeded",
                "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
            },
            "eventTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:47:02.0657952Z",
            "submissionTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:49:03.137537Z"
        },
        {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "eventName": {
                "value": "EndRequest",
                "localizedValue": "EndRequest"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxx/extensions/enablevmaccess/events/xxxxxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxxxxx",
            "level": "Informational",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxx",
            "resourceProviderName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute"
            },
            "operationName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write"
            },
            "status": {
                "value": "Succeeded",
                "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
            },
            "eventTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:47:02.0657952Z",
            "submissionTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:49:03.137537Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

Here the code I am trying:

```
d_date = datetime.datetime.now()
today = d_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print(today)

N = 10
date_N_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)
start_date = date_N_days_ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print(start_date)

vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
for vm_general in vm_list:
    general_view = vm_general.id.split("/")
    resource_group = general_view[4]
    print(resource_group)

    BASE_URL = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge {start_date} and eventTimestamp le {today} and resourceGroupName eq {resource_group}&$select=eventName,id,resourceGroupName,resourceProviderName,operationName,status,eventTimestamp,correlationId,submissionTimestamp,level"
    
    BASE_URL = BASE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + credential.token["access_token"]
    }
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)
    
    # if i convert below line to df_json = response.json() it says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
    df_json = response.text  # this is a string but i am able to parse it properly in json forammter
    
    print(df_json)
    
    with open('c:\csv\logs_test.csv', 'w') as f:
        for key in df_json.keys():
            f.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, df_json[key]))
    break
```

I am getting error like:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Expected result:

```
Actually I need to to write to xls (excel) format having columns as "correlationId,eventName,id,resourceGroupName,resourceProviderName,operationName,status,eventTimestamp,submissionTimestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to convert to pandas dataframe and then to `xls` file.
You will to have to install `xlwt` - `pip install xlwt`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "value": [
        {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "eventName": {
                "value": "EndRequest",
                "localizedValue": "EndRequest"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxx/extensions/enablevmaccess/events/xxxxxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxxxxx",
            "level": "Informational",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxx",
            "resourceProviderName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute"
            },
            "operationName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write"
            },
            "status": {
                "value": "Succeeded",
                "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
            },
            "eventTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:47:02.0657952Z",
            "submissionTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:49:03.137537Z"
        },
        {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "eventName": {
                "value": "EndRequest",
                "localizedValue": "EndRequest"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxx/extensions/enablevmaccess/events/xxxxxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxxxxx",
            "level": "Informational",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxx",
            "resourceProviderName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute"
            },
            "operationName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write"
            },
            "status": {
                "value": "Succeeded",
                "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
            },
            "eventTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:47:02.0657952Z",
            "submissionTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:49:03.137537Z"
        }
    ]
}

df = pd.json_normalize(data['value'])
cols = ["correlationId","eventName.value","id","resourceGroupName","resourceProviderName.value","operationName.value","status.value","eventTimestamp","submissionTimestamp"]

df[cols].to_excel("data.xls", index=False)
```

Instead of json, use `demjson`. Install the library - `pip install demjson` because `json` parses correctly only if it's a proper json.

```
import demjson

data = demjson.decode(response.text)

# remaining code goes on
```

Comment: `df = pd.json_normalize(a['value'])` should be `df = pd.json_normalize(data['value'])` ?

Comment: Thanks @asp Corrected

Comment: getting this error now     `df = pd.json_normalize(data['value'])`
`TypeError: 'data' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: `data` should be a json object.

Comment: how can i convert that response to json object ?

Comment: Hi, i get `File"C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1640, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['correlationId', 'eventName.value', 'id', 'resourceGroupName',\n       'resourceProviderName.value', 'operationName.value', 'status.value',\n       'eventTimestamp', 'submissionTimestamp'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: @asp Are you sure that the json is similar to as is in the question?

Comment: Yeah , its exactly, same huh. dont know what happening

Comment: Try changing the column names... get the column names from the dataframe

Comment: let me give a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219355/discussion-between-asp-and-bigbounty).

Comment: `raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['correlationId', 'eventName.value', 'id', 'resourceGroupName',\n       'resourceProviderName.value', 'operationName.value', 'status.value',\n       'eventTimestamp', 'submissionTimestamp'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" ` how can we handle if there is null of index

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use eval to convert the text to a dictionary and then use pandas to convert it to an excel file.

```
import pandas

response_dict = eval(response.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(response_dict['value'])
df['tag'] = "Managed by IT"

file_name = 'data.xls'
df.to_excel(file_name, index = False)
```

Comment: how to add column names here in this example pls

Comment: getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt', do we need to mention any engine ?

Comment: I am able to see excel now, but is there a way to customise column names and also I need to add one more vairable as anoother column and value should be repeated for all these rows in excel...

Comment: Hi @asp, Pandas can take the keys as column names by default. Unless you want to change the column names, you need not specifically do anything.

Comment: can i add another variable in program to resulting dataframe and repeat the value for all rows ?

Comment: df.columns = [list of column names in order]

Comment: yes, you can do, df['new_column_name'] = 'value_you_want_to_repeat'

Comment: can i add additional column for all rows into this resulting dataframe ? for example i have varible called tag = "Managed by IT" , i wanted to add this as new column in dataframe and there by in excel sheet for all rows of above json.. possible ?

Comment: Yes, please add, df['tag'] = "Managed by IT", you will see the new column